# How to configure ProGuard to omit methods with SuppressWarnings("unused")

Tags: java, android, proguard, suppress-warnings, objectanimator

I have methods that are used by Android framework `ObjectAnimator` instances. Hence they appear to be unused (they are used through reflection) and I add `SuppressWarnings("unused")` annotation, so IntelliJ don't show warnings for them. However, ProGuard still strips them and I need to explicitly tell him not to. This is tedious and seems redundant (violates DRY). Is it possible to configure ProGuard not to remove methods with `SuppressWarnings("unused")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options that tell ProGuard to keep some classes and members (fields and methods) are described in the official documentation: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoptions.

You can tell ProGuard to preserve class members using:

```
-keepclassmembers class_specification
```

Your `class_specification` will look like:

```
class * {
    @java.lang.SuppressWarnings <methods>;
}
```

So, in your [`proguard.cfg`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#configuring) you should have something like this:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @java.lang.SuppressWarnings <methods>;
}
```

Comment: So one thing that concerns me, is that I can't specify SupressWarning("unused"), but only SupressWarning. Proguard will now preserve everything, independent of warning type.

Comment: @gruszczy You're absolutely right. As far as I know, in ProGuard we can't specify that.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to poke a dead thread but I recently ran into this and discovered it is not possible. Because `SuppressWarnings` has `SOURCE` level retention it is not in the class file processed by Proguard ([as covered in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40781837/6526330)). I ended up using android support's `@Keep` annotation instead and configuring it with a rule similar to Adam's:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
  @proguard.annotation.Keep <methods>;
}
```

Comment: I had it work by using `@android.support.annotation.Keep` instead of `@proguard.annotation.Keep`.

Comment: To who migrated to AndroidX, remember to use `@androidx.annotation.Keep`

Answer (score 1):

I've faced similar stripping problem with Dexguard. I've solved in a really dirty way, placing this somewhere:

```
if(System.currentTimeMillis() < 0 ){ //never happens
   //..
   //TODO directly invoke stripped methods
   //..
}
```

Comment: This takes care of ProGuard as well as the compiler, especially private/protected methods that are called by reflection alone.  My classes have a method called "registerMethods" where the reflection-only methods are added by a custom annotation processor.